# fmt:message adding unintentional comma into number

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I've found strange behavior with the format tag library. I'm formatting a copyright message in the footer of a webpage. I'm using the following pseudo code:

```
<fmt:message var="copyright" key="someKey">
    <fmt:param value="${year}"/>
</fmt:message>

...

<c:out value="${copyright}"/>
```

I'm just passing the year as an argument into the resource bundle.  If you c-out the year value before passing it in:

```
<c:out value="${year}"/>
<%-- renders as 2012 --%>
```

But after the argument gets passed in, the year gets formatted as a number.  The number is rendered as 2,012.

I've googled and asked around and haven't found anything besides the generic Oracle documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html)

Has anyone else reached this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been interpreted as a [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) by [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) and hence being formatted with a thousands separator which can be a comma or a dot, depending on the current locale. You can prevent it being interpreted as a `Number` by adding a [zero width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space):

```html
<fmt:param value="${year}&#8203;"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but after playing around discovered that only number types will be formatted. If you make year a string first then it won't:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int currYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
String cYear = Integer.toString(currYear);

<fmt:message key="msg.parameterized"><fmt:param value="<%=currYear%>"/></fmt:message>
<fmt:message key="msg.parameterized"><fmt:param value="<%=cYear%>"/></fmt:message>
```

The first one will contain 2,012 and the second just 2012

Answer (score 0):

Whilst [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12905859/889583) is simple and superficially effective, it feels a little, well, impure to me.  For a start, someone else might come along one day and wonder what on Earth that extra character is for and maybe even remove it.

Since `<fmt:message />` uses Java's built-in [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class under the hood, we can just insert a formatting pattern in the ResourceBundle's message string itself.

For example, in your ResourceBundle you could have:

```
someKey = Copyright (c) {0,number,#} ACME Inc.
```

The `#` here can in fact be any format string as documented in the [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class.  In this case, `#` alone just outputs the number without any additional formatting.

---

As an aside, since in this particular instance you want to output a year, you could pass a java.util.Date instance as the value in `<fmt:param />` and use the following in your ResourceBundle:

```
someKey = Copyright (c) {0,date,yyyy} ACME Inc.
```

In this case, any [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) format string can be used instead of `yyyy`.